# What is signal dimension

Tags: self-study, signal-processing, signal-detection

[Estimating Unknown Sparsity in Compressed Sensing](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v28/lopes13.pdf) is a paper about sparse signal. I am just learning the concepts. In the first paragraph, it says that when the number of observation data samples $n$ is less than the signal dimension $p$, then the desired signal $x$ is sparse. I have never come across he term signal dimension. Can somebody please explain what is signal dimension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal dimension $p$ refers to the dimension of the signal. The paper in question specifies that it is working in $R^p$, not ($R^1$) because the author wants to take into account multiple dimensions. For example, if your data is a geographic location, you have dimension $p=3$ because the complete description requires 3 numbers: longitude, latitude and altitude.

Comment: That means it is the number of variables?Can you please explain with an example equation?Or is it like a vector auto regressive model?

Comment: No that does not mean the number of variables. I gave you an example of geographic location. If that is your variable, you need 3 numbers to completely describe the geographic location of an object: longitude, latitude and altitude. For example, point A is located at co-ordinates (x,y,z). It has nothing to do with vector auto-regressive model. It is not a model at all, just a description.

Comment: Are they the number of coefficients of a linear regression model, say auto regression model of order 2: AR(2) then is signal dimension p=2?

Comment: No. It is not the number of coefficients of any model. It is just the complete description of a single variable. It has nothing to do with the dimension of a model. AR(2) tells you nothing about the dimension of the signal.

Comment: Ok, so by looking at the signal is there a way to know what the dimension is? The thing is I am learning about sparse regression, and everywhere I get is that the signal dimension must be greater than number of samples observed. So, in this context how do I determine if the model is sparse or not if nothing is reflected in the functional form of the model equation?Shall be obliged for your insights into this matter.

Comment: In the other answer given after you, @ssdecontrol says that it is a multivariate signal with p components. Both of your answers are different, or maybe my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: You know the dimension of the signal by looking at the type of variable you are studying. If you are studying geographic location, you know that you need 3 numbers, so p=3. If you are studying interest rate, you need the rate and time, two numbers, so p=2.

Comment: The answers are the same. The only difference is that I am using the example of geographic location whereas @ssdecontrol is using the color code on a computer. Once again, the model (AR(2) or whatever model you want, and the variable you are trying to study) are two different things that don't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: But he mentions multivariate, however you said that it is nothing to do with multivariate. Can you please put up an AR or MA model since my question is related to linear regression of AR,MA of higher dimension. So, for AR or MA model what do we mean by dimensionality?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with AR, MA or any other type of model. The word "multivariate" can be used to describe a model and/or a variable. A model and a variable are two different things. This is an English comprehension issue that you need to clarify on your own before studying this further. You can have a multivariate model with univariate variables. You can also have a multivariate model with multivariate variables.

Answer (score 1):

Signal dimension is just the dimension of the random variable that is the signal. "Dimension $p$" is a slightly sloppy way of stating the dimension of the support of the random variable is $p$. That is, it's a multivariate signal with $p$ components.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example of what a multivariate signal is?How it looks like in eQuation form?

Comment: Color on a computer screen is a 3-dimensional signal of red, green, and blue. This would be represented as a vector $color = (red, green, blue) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Both of your answers are different. Does dimensionality means multivariate signal where each variable = dimension?So, in linear regression I will have 3 equations if dimension = 3?Can you please explain with AR model?

Comment: It's a matter of interpretation. You can think of "color" as one variable, or "red," "green," and "blue" as three separate variables.